Adam's $\beta_1$ fixed in practice but required to depend on $t$ for convergence proofs
In the paper ADAM: A METHOD FOR STOCHASTIC OPTIMIZATION, the exponential moving average parameter $\beta_1$ is set to $0.9$ as default in most ML/DL APIs but the convergence proof requires that $\beta_1 = \beta_{1,t}$, a function of $t$. All variants of proofs of Adam convergence I have seen require dependence of $\beta_1$ on iteration $t$, and I understand why this is needed for the method to converge.
What I don't understand is why a fixed $\beta_1$ is recommended in practice instead of a time varying $\beta_1$.
Thanks for your help.

The trouble with having $\beta_1$ vary with t is, basically, how fast?  This becomes another parameter to fix or tune. If you make it too fast, your algorithm may appear to converge to a point that is quite far away from the optimum solution, even though if you let it run for a long time, it would slowly get to where it's supposed to go.  With $\beta_1$ near 1 but fixed, you are more-or-less guaranteed to get to the vicinity of an optimum, then wander around in a small region near it - one in which, hopefully, suboptimality is not severe.  So, fixed $\beta_1$ mitigates the worst-case result.

@jbowman Does this mean the default parameters in Adam by design will never attain optimality? Rereading the paper again, I noticed anything just less than 1 is best for the lambda parameter, in which case the $\beta_{1,t}$ is as close to $\beta_1$ as possible even for very high iterations. See demo in Desmos: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/yeyl4gjjc5

That is correct.  But with stochastic optimization, you'll never really reach optimality anyway. With the parameter fixed, you're much less likely to fool your convergence criterion into believing you've converged when you haven't, so that's the upside.

@jbowman I get it that by letting $\beta_{1,t}$ decay in time, you are giving more weights to $g_t$ than the moving average as time progresses but what I don't get is how this is more likely to fool the convergence criterion about convergence.
